# How to declare all API calling in single class file and call whatever API name we need to use for other view controller class

Tags: ios, swift

I have some 10 API URLs like `login,signup,forgotpassword,displaydata,mapcalling.php's urls`.

Now I will create some view controller class to declare all the URL.

Like say, I am in my loginviewcontroller.swift class.Now here I need to call login.php URL to validate the username & password and allow user to enter to app.Like this we will call each API URL to all view controller.swift file classes.

So what my doubt is:

It's possible to create one separate file or class and declare all the API in that single file. Like:

```
let link1 = "url" 
let link2 = "url" 
let link3 = "url" 
let link4 = "url" 
let link5 = "url"
```

And call the needed URL to other view controller, by calling the declared object names. Like say, in my `loginviewcontroller.swift` file if we need to call my `login.php` URL.

Instead of calling the URL I need to call `link1` to my `loginviewcontroller.swift` file.

How do I code in that separate class and how can I import that header to my other view controller for using the URL object name?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can create a Swift class that serves as a facade for your server.  In that way, any of your controllers can access functions in the class as if they were talking to the server.

For example:

```
class ServerAccess {
    static let link1 = "url1"

    static func sendLoginRequest() {
        print(link1)
    }
}
```

Since it's Swift, you don't need imports, just reference the class in your controller as needed.  (If the `ServerAccess` class needs to maintain state, it can be a shared instance instead of using class methods.)

```
ServerAccess.sendLoginRequest()
```

Comment: Yes this is what i have asked.But i have one question??,That is !! If i need to call my `link1` url to my `loginviewcontroller.swift` then how can i call???..Like say in loginviewcontroller.swift file its like this !! - nsurl * url = myurl. So here instead of hadcode the url , How can i call url as `link1`..and the swift class is nsobject or normal swift file ??

Comment: You can use `ServerAccess.link1` if you must use it in another object.

Comment: okay.Then the separate class should be as `nsobject` class or normal `swift file`

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference to this usage.

Comment: Sorry din get you ??.